A component claim that is too broad
In a patent application, there is a method claim and a system claim.
Method claim:

receiving user data from a client device;

processing the received user data to generate personalized recommendations;

storing the user data in a database for future reference;

communicating with third-party APIs to retrieve additional information; and

facilitating real-time interactions between users through a messaging interface.


Systemt claim:
A server adapted to at least one of:

receive user data from a client device;

process the received user data to generate personalized recommendations;

store the user data in a database for future reference;

communicate with third-party APIs to retrieve additional information; and

facilitate real-time interactions between users through a messaging interface.


My main concern is the "at least one of" part of the system claim.
Would the system claim be rejected for being too broad?
For example, a server that is adapted to only "4. communicate with third-party APIs to retrieve additional information" would meet the requirements of the claim.
But if this is the only function the server can perform, clearly it is not the intended invention defined in the Method claim?
Questions:

If the "at least one of" part is not removed, Will the System claim be rejected?


Numbering portions of a claim numerically can be confusing. You might edit to use lower case letters.

Each claim is its own, separate, infringe-able thing. The scope of a system claim is not tied to the scope of a similar method claim.
In your example the claim will be rejected (or later found invalid) if any single one of the unrelated things on the list is covered by prior art. It is hard to imagine it as something crafted by someone knowledgeable.
Claims aren’t “too broad” on their face other than extreme cases. Their broadest reasonable interpretation reads on done prior art that the examiner finds and cites.
